# Does CMake's find_library search LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: cmake

Despite reading the documentation I can't figure out whether CMake's command [`find_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) searches or not the directories listed in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

My tests give mixed results.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for LIBRARY_PATH? For gcc there is also the --print-search-dirs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation (I didn't reproduced the text related to cmake variables nor parameters of `find_library`, which are not relevant here):

> If `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` is specified, then no additional paths are added to the search. If `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` is not specified, the search process is as follows:
>
> ...
>
> 4. Search the standard system environment variables. This can be skipped if `NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH` is an argument.
>
>    - Directories in `LIB`. On Windows hosts: `<prefix>/lib/<arch>` if `CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE` is set, and `<prefix>/lib` for each `<prefix>/[s]bin` in `PATH`, and `<entry>/lib` for other entries in `PATH`, and the directories in `PATH` itself.
>
> ...

So `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not used by `find_library`. This is confirmed reading the [source code](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmFindLibraryCommand.h).

The mixed results of your tests may come from an other variable, but without a detailed description of these tests, this is just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

According to the current documentation and a small test, it seems that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not considered.

---

The documentation for [`find_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/find_library.html) says

> If `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` is specified, then no additional paths are added
>   to the search. If `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` is not specified, the search
>   process is as follows:
>
> 1. Search paths specified in cmake-specific cache variables. These
>      are intended to be used on the command line with a `-DVAR=value`.
>      This can be skipped if `NO_CMAKE_PATH` is passed.
>
>    - `<prefix>/lib/<arch>` if CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE is set,
>        and `<prefix>/lib` for each `<prefix>` in `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`
>    - `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH`
>    - `CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH`
> 2. Search paths specified in cmake-specific environment variables.
>      These are intended to be set in the user’s shell configuration.
>      This can be skipped if `NO_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH` is passed.
>
>    - `<prefix>/lib/<arch>` if `CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE` is set,
>        and `<prefix>/lib` for each `<prefix>` in `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`
>    - `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH`
>    - `CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH`
> 3. Search the paths specified by the `HINTS` option. These should be
>      paths computed by system introspection, such as a hint provided by
>      the location of another item already found. Hard-coded guesses
>      should be specified with the `PATHS` option.
> 4. Search the standard system environment variables. This can be
>      skipped if `NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH` is an argument.
>
>    - Directories in `LIB`, `<prefix>/lib/<arch>` if
>        `CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE` is set, and `<prefix>/lib` for
>        each `<prefix>/[s]bin` in `PATH`, and `<entry>/lib` for other
>        entries in `PATH`, and the directories in `PATH` itself.
> 5. Search cmake variables defined in the Platform files for the
>      current system. This can be skipped if `NO_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH` is
>      passed.
>
>    - `<prefix>/lib/<arch>` if `CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE` is set,
>        and `<prefix>/lib` for each `<prefix>` in
>        `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH`
>    - `CMAKE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_PATH`
>    - `CMAKE_SYSTEM_FRAMEWORK_PATH`
> 6. Search the paths specified by the `PATHS` option or in the
>      short-hand version of the command. These are typically hard-coded
>      guesses.

Since [`CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html#variable:CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH) and [`CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH.html#variable:CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH) are specified to be empty (by default), the question is equivalent to the following: Is `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` considered by [`CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH.html#variable:CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH) or [`CMAKE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_PATH.html#variable:CMAKE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_PATH). According to a simple test I made with *CMake 3.7.1*, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not considered by them.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is in the article:
https://bbs.huaweicloud.com/blogs/366824
Here is a way to find library via LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
string(REPLACE ":" ";" RUNTIME_PATH "$ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}")
find_library(SOME_API NAMES jvm HINTS ${RUNTIME_PATH})
```